# poker probability

Tags: probability

a pack of poker contains 52 cards and we are going to flip through one by one so the probability of the following events are

1. a king right after the first ace ?
2. an ace right after the first ace ?
3. the first ace is the 10-th card?
4. the probability the next card is the ace of spades, if the  first ace is the 30-th card?
5. The probability the next card is the jack of diamonds If the 
   first ace is the 30-th card?

I have tried the (1)(2)(3) and not sure is right or not,but no idea with the (4) (5)

(1)$\frac{4}{52}*\frac{4}{51}$ and which is same prob as (2)

(3)$\frac{48}{52}*\frac{47}{51}*\frac{46}{50}*\frac{45}{49}*\frac{44}{48}*\frac{43}{47}*\frac{42}{46}*\frac{41}{45}*\frac{40}{44}*\frac{4}{43}$but any simpler way to write it out?

Comment: Not following you for $1$.   There is nothing special about the slot following the first $A$.  The probability that it is a king is just $\frac 4{51}$.

Comment: I'm not following either of you. What if the first ace comes in third place?

Comment: For your intuition:  for card value $i$ let $p_i$ denote the probability that the slot after the first ace is occupied with a card of value $i$.  Then by symmetry we must have $p_i=p_j$ so long as neither $i$ nor $j$ equals $A$.  But if your value were correct, the probability that that slot was taken by a non-ace would then be $12p_i=12\times \frac 4{52}\times\frac 4{51}=0.07239819$ which is absurdly low.

Comment: @GitGud  If you fix the slot for the first $A$, at $3$ to stick with your example, then the probability that the next card is also an $A$ is $\frac {3}{49}$.  By symmetry, the other values all have the same probability, which would be $\frac 1{12}\times \left(1-\frac {3}{49}\right)$.

Comment: @GitGud  After further thought, I think I have it slightly wrong.  I think the answer is $\frac 4{52}$ regardless of the card value.  I will post an argument below.

Comment: By the way, good question (+1).  I find myself confused by it, and unsure of my computation.  I've written it out below, but I don't like it and I hope someone else can either spot the error or improve on the argument.

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer $1$ in detail, as my comment was inaccurate.

Note:  I am unhappy with this argument, but I don't see a flaw in it. I'd be grateful if someone could either spot the blunder or supply a better argument.

Key Remark:  By symmetry, the probability that the card following the first $A$ has value $i$ is independent of $i$ for all values different from $A$. Call this common value $p$ and let $p_A$ denote the probability that the card following the first $A$ is also an $A$.  Of course we have $$12p+p_A=1\implies p=\frac 1{12}\times\left(1-p_A\right)$$

Let's compute $p_A$.

If the first $A$ appears in slot $k$ then we get $p_A(k)=\frac 3{52-k}$, where $p_A(k)$ denotes the conditional probability that the card after the first $A$ is also an $A$ conditioned on the event that the first $A$ appears in slot $k$. Now, the probability that the first $A$ appears in slot $k$ is $$\frac {48}{52}\times\frac{47}{51}\times \cdots \times \frac {48-(k-2)}{52-(k-2)}\times \frac 4{52-(k-1)}$$  It follows that $$p_A=\sum_{k=1}^{49}\left(\frac {48}{52}\times\frac{47}{51}\times \cdots \times \frac {48-(k-2)}{52-(k-2)}\times \frac 4{52-(k-1)}\times \frac 3{52-k}\right)$$

Computing that sum numerically we get $p_A=\frac 4{52}$  Which implies that $p=\frac 4{52}$.

Sanity Check:  Suppose we only had a $4$ card deck, $\{A,A,K,K\}$.  Then there are six possible shuffles, namely $AAKK,AKAK,AKKA,KAAK,KAKA,KKAA$.  The card following the first $A$ is $\{A,K,K,A,K,A\}$ so the probability that it is $A$ equals the probability that it is $K$.

Comment: oh, my goodness.  I simplified this to a 4 card deck with kings and 2 Aces.  there are 24 permutations, and half of them, the first king follows the first ace, and half of them, the aces are consecutive.  Where is my logic failing me?

Comment: @DougM  Welcome to the club.  I feel I am missing something obvious.  That's why I did the computation by brutal summation.  Not to say I never screw up a direct computation, but it is usually easier to keep conceptual error out of that sort of thing.

Comment: what is the 12p+=a=1 mean and when plug in pa=4/52 it is 1/13 for p

Comment: @Ccnoc  The only value which might be different is Ace, yes?  That is, it's quite clear that there's no difference between $K$ and $4$, say.  So call that common value $p$.  At first we allow that the Ace probability might be different, so call that probability $p_A$.  It follows that $p_A+12p=1$ since the card has to have some value.  True, eventually we see that $p_A=p$ but, to me at least, that takes some thinking,

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bijection on the set of all deck orders:

$$(c_1,c_2,\dots, c_{m-1}, A, c_{m+1},\dots, c_{52} )
\longleftrightarrow (c_{m+1},\dots, c_{52}, A, c_1,c_2,\dots, c_{m-1}),$$

where $A$ is an ace, and none of $c_1,\dots, c_{m-1}$ is an ace.

Therefore the card following the first ace,
 that is $c_{m+1}$,  is equally likely to be any of the 52 cards, since the top card of a thoroughly shuffled deck has this property.
In other words, 
the statistical distribution of "card following first ace" and "top card" are the same.

Comment: Not following.  What you call $FA$ won't be the first ace in the second ordering...

Comment: @lulu That is not relevant. Focus on the card $c_{m+1}$.

Comment: Sorry, I must be being dense. We have some information about the value of  $c_{m+1}$...as we know an ace precedes it there is some reason to imagine that it is less likely to be an ace.  Nor do I understand your bijection.  If I take the "standard ordering"  $\{2\clubsuit, 3\clubsuit,\cdots, A\spadesuit\}$, what is it's preimage?

Comment: $(A\spadesuit,2\clubsuit,3\clubsuit,\dots)\longleftrightarrow (2\clubsuit,3\clubsuit,\dots,A\spadesuit)$

Comment: What I mean to say is, $FA$ is only defined on the left hand.  We know it isn't the first ace on the right hand.  Did you mean to say $LA$?

Comment: On the right, it is the last ace; that's how I know that this is a bijection. But all of this is irrelevant to the question. Once I know that this is a bijection then I know that the statistical distribution of "card following first ace" and "top card" are the same.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand the definition of the bijection.  To define the inverse, i need to refer to the last ace, no?  Ok.  I think I am persuaded.  Do you find this intuitive?  Personally, I find it unexpected.

Comment: Thanks, I think that clarifies the problem (for me, at least).

Answer (score 0):

King right after the first ace?  What you show is the chance of the first two cards being A,K.  It is inevitable that an A comes off sooner or later.
$\frac 4{52}$

2) While it would seem that 2 is not the same as 1, the more I calculate, the more that I think it is. 
$\frac 4{52}$

3)First Ace is the 10th card is correct, but this is cleaner.

$(\frac {48!}{39!}\frac {42!}{52!})4$

4) $(\frac 34)$ the first ace is not the ace of spades.

$(\frac 34)(\frac 1{22})$ the first ace is not the ace of spades, the 31 card is the ace of spades, given that the first 30 are not the ace of spades.

5) The rough approach.  The J of daimonds could be in one of 51 locations, including is space number 31.
However, that there are no aces in the first 29 cards flipped means that there is a greater than fair probability that the 31st card is an A, so it should be slighly less.

$P(\text{No A no J of D in first 29 cards}) = \frac {47!}{(47-29)!} \frac {52!}{(52-29)!}\\
P(\text{No A in first 29 cards}) = \frac {48!}{(48-29)!} \frac {52!}{(52-29)!}$

$P(\text{No A no J of D in first 29 cards|No A in first 29 cards}) = \frac {47!}{(47-29)!} \frac {(48-29)!}{48!} = \frac {19}{48}$

$P(\text{No A no J of D in first 29 cards|No A in first 29 cards})P(\text{J on card 31|A on card 30}) = \frac {19}{48}\frac {1}{22}$

Comment: I now agree with the answer $\frac 4{52}$ for part $1$ but why is it obvious?  After all, it appears that that slot is less likely to be occupied by an $A$ as we are sure that one $A$ is gone.

Comment: @lulu you are absolutely correct.  I need to think on 5 for a few minutes more.

Comment: Yeah...I also got $\frac 4{51}$, by symmetry but I no longer believe it.  Check out my post below, see if you can find a blunder or a better argument.  The problem is that, should the first $A$ be far down the pack, the probability that the following one is also an $A$ increases a lot.  But, perhaps I am still confused.

Comment: is that the part 5 is wrong my answer is 19/24288

Answer (score 0):

1) King follows First Ace.

Let's not worry about suits or values of the other cards.  Take a pack of four king of hearts, four ace of spades, and forty four jokers.

There are $52!/(4!4!44!)$ equally probable ways to arrange this deck.

Set aside one king, shuffle the remaining cards, stick that king after the first ace.  There are $51!/(3!4!44!)$ ways to do this.

So the probability of the event is $\quad\dfrac 1 {13}$

---

2) Ace follows First Ace.

As above, so below.

Set aside one ace.   There are $51!/(4!3!44!)$ ways to sort 4 kings, 3 aces, 44 jokers (and stick the set aside ace behind the first ace).   Coincidentally yielding the same probability of $1/13$.

---

3) First Ace is tenth card.

Take 4 ace of spades and 48 jokers.  $52!/(4!48!)$ ways to arrange them in total.  Now count ways to arrange 9 jokers, an ace in tenth place, and then all the rest (3 aces, 39 jokers).

---

4) Ace of spades follows first ace when that is in 30th place.

The deck consists of three ace of hearts, one ace of spades, and 48 jokers.  The deck is shuffled so we have 29 jokers, an ace, in that order, and then the rest (3 aces, 19 jokers) in any order.

If the first ace is spades, it cannot follow itself.   Multiply the probability that it is not, by the conditional probability of the event given that.

---

5) Jack of Diamonds follows First Ace when that is in thirtieth place.

The deck consists of four ace of hearts, jack of diamond, and 47 jokers, shuffled so we have 29 cards, an aces, and then the rest.

If the jack is among the 29 cards before first ace, then it cannot follow it.   Multiply the probability that it is not, by the conditional probability of the event given that.